# how to get value as type and add into one textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

there is 4 fields like

```
<input id="address01" name="address01" class="text large" />
<input id="address02" name="address02" class="text large" />
<input id="address03" name="address03" class="text large" />
<input id="address04" name="address04" class="text large" />
```

and

```
<textarea id="address_oneline" name="address_oneline" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
```

what im looking for is way to get the text from address01 to 04 fields as user type and put into address_oneline text area.

im using jquery

any help would be great

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
$('input[id^=address]').keyup(function(){
    var finalval = '';
    $('input[id^=address]').each(function(){
        finalval += $(this).val();
    });
    $('#address_oneline').val(finalval);
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ApreZ/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[id^="address"]').each(function(){
     $('#address_oneline').append(this.value + "  ");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ZKS82/

Answer (score 1):

**change as you type**

```
jQuery(function(){

    $('input[id^="address"]').bind('keyup',function(){
        $('#address_oneline').empty();
        $('input[id^="address"]').each(function() {
            $('#address_oneline').append(this.value + "\n");
        });
    })

});

<input id="address01" name="address01" class="text large" />
<input id="address02" name="address02" class="text large" />
<input id="address03" name="address03" class="text large" />
<input id="address04" name="address04" class="text large" />

<textarea id="address_oneline" name="address_oneline" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hF4wj/